# I cannot insert new records into a table using this query caused by an error

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Goal is to insert **new records ONLY** to update the table that I just created, but it gives me an error message 102 just as written below. When I higlight or click the error message on the error message area in SSMS. It highlights the **ss.sitedesc=b.sitedesc** part of the script. I don't see anything wrong with it. Could someone help me please? thank you.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 39
Incorrect syntax near 'ss'.

[image]

This is currently my whole script.

```
insert into SEC_ODS.dbo.ODSCustomerBase    
select 
--Identity as CustomerBaseID
'E4SE' as Recordsource, 
'C' as RecordType, 
ss.siteURN,
ss.sitedesc,
ss.FS_URL + 'frmcustomer.aspx?CustomerID=' + customerid as CustomerLink,
co.HomeCurrencyCode, 
c.customerid, 
c.currencycode as customercurrencycode,
c.entityname as CustomerName, 
c.entityshortname CustomerShortName, 
c.address, 
c.city, 
c.postalcode, 
c.countrycode, 
cn.countryname, 
c.statecode,
s.statename, 
c.phone,
c.fax, 
c.taxcode, 
c.prospectid,
c.createdate, 
c.lastupdatedate 
from country cn, 
SECSite ss, 
company co, 
customer c 
left outer join state s 
on c.statecode = s.statecode
where  ss.LocalSiteFlag = 1
and cn.countrycode = c.countrycode

and not exists(select * from SEC_ODS.dbo.ODSCustomerBase b
                where(ss.siteURN=b.siteURN
                      ss.sitedesc=b.sitedesc
                      ss.FS_URL=b.FS_URL
                      co.HomeCurrencyCode=b.HomeCurrencyCode
                      c.customerid=b.customerid
                      c.currencycode=b.currencycode
                      c.entityname=b.entityname
                      c.entityshortname=b.entityshortname
                      c.address=b.address
                      c.city=b.city
                      c.postalcode=b.postalcode
                      c.countrycode=b.countrycode
                      cn.countryname=b.countryname
                      c.statecode=b.statecode
                      s.statename=b.statename
                      c.phone=b.phone
                      c.fax=b.fax
                      c.taxcode=b.taxcode
                      c.prospectid=b.prospectid
                      c.createdate=b.createdate
                      c.lastupdatedate=b.lastupdatedate))
```

But when I put AND under the where condition.

It prompts me an error with the following invalid columns

[image]

This is the script that I used to create the table. This might help.

```
USE SEC_ODS
GO 
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[ODSCustomerBase]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [ODSCustomerBase]
Go
Create Table ODSCustomerBase
(CustomerBaseID             int NOT NULL identity primary key,
RecordSource            nvarchar(4),
RecordType              varchar(2),
SiteURN             nvarchar(128)NOT NULL,
SiteDesc                    nvarchar(60)NULL,
CustomerLink            nvarchar(120)NOT NULL,
HomeCurrencyCode            nvarchar(8)NOT NULL, 
CustomerID                  nvarchar(15)NOT NULL,
CustomerCurrencyCode        nvarchar(8)NOT NULL,
CustomerName            nvarchar(120)NULL,
CustomerShortName           nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
Address             nvarchar(255)NULL,
City                    nvarchar(25)NULL,
PostalCode              nvarchar(10) NULL,
CountryCode             nvarchar(3) NOT NULL,
CountryName             nvarchar(60) NOT NULL,
StateCode               nvarchar(8) NULL,
StateName               nvarchar(60) NULL,
Phone                   nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
Fax                 nvarchar(30) NULL,
TaxCode             nvarchar(15) NULL,
ProspectID              nvarchar(15) NULL,
CreateDate              datetime NOT NULL,
LastUpdateDate          datetime NULL)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a logical operator between statements. Like this:

```
... ss.siteURN=b.siteURN
                  ss.sitedesc=b.sitedesc AND
                  ss.FS_URL=b.FS_URL AND
                  co.HomeCurrencyCode=b.HomeCurrencyCode AND
                  c.customerid=b.customerid  ...
```

Comment: Hi Jokey. It still have some errors on the columns that I aliased.

Comment: Looks like your table "SECSite" doesn't contain column "FS_URL". Also check columns "currencycode", "entityname" and "entityshortname".

Answer (score 0):

In where clause you may miss the AND keyword

```
where(ss.siteURN=b.siteURN
                AND  ss.sitedesc=b.sitedesc
                AND  ss.FS_URL=b.FS_URL
```

.....

Answer (score 0):

please read syntex of insert query like :
insert into tablename(columname1, columnname2, ..) value(value1, valkue2,..)

So, your query look like at below, where you need a change columnname which as per table column name:

```
insert into SEC_ODS.dbo.ODSCustomerBase(columnname1, columnname2, ...)    
select 
--Identity as CustomerBaseID
'E4SE' as Recordsource, 
'C' as RecordType, 
ss.siteURN,
ss.sitedesc,
ss.FS_URL + 'frmcustomer.aspx?CustomerID=' + customerid as CustomerLink,
co.HomeCurrencyCode, 
c.customerid, 
c.currencycode as customercurrencycode,
c.entityname as CustomerName, 
c.entityshortname CustomerShortName, 
c.address, 
c.city, 
c.postalcode, 
c.countrycode, 
cn.countryname, 
c.statecode,
s.statename, 
c.phone,
c.fax, 
c.taxcode, 
c.prospectid,
c.createdate, 
c.lastupdatedate 
from country cn, 
SECSite ss, 
company co, 
customer c 
left outer join state s 
on c.statecode = s.statecode
where  ss.LocalSiteFlag = 1
and cn.countrycode = c.countrycode
and not exists(select columnaname3 from SEC_ODS.dbo.ODSCustomerBase b
                where(ss.siteURN=b.siteURN  and
                      ss.sitedesc=b.sitedesc  and
                      ss.FS_URL=b.FS_URL  and
                      co.HomeCurrencyCode=b.HomeCurrencyCode  and
                      c.customerid=b.customerid  and
                      c.currencycode=b.currencycode  and
                      c.entityname=b.entityname  and
                      c.entityshortname=b.entityshortname  and
                      c.address=b.address  and
                      c.city=b.city  and
                      c.postalcode=b.postalcode  and
                      c.countrycode=b.countrycode  and
                      cn.countryname=b.countryname  and
                      c.statecode=b.statecode  and
                      s.statename=b.statename  and
                      c.phone=b.phone  and
                      c.fax=b.fax  and
                      c.taxcode=b.taxcode  and
                      c.prospectid=b.prospectid  and
                      c.createdate=b.createdate  and
                      c.lastupdatedate=b.lastupdatedate))
```